# Hazelcast MultiMap expire key

Tags: hazelcast, ttl

In an normal hazelcast map i know you can se the key expiry via

```
put(K key, V value, long ttl, TimeUnit timeunit)
```

But does someone knows, if I can set the TTL for an entry in an MultiMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik this functionality is not available for a MultiMap. It is missing a lot of features compared to the IMap.

Comment: @pveentjer may you look pls at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359970/intellij-show-full-stack-trace-on-debugging-concurrent-3rd-party-lib. I'm trying to debug communication of two Hazelcast instances, but fail to get full stack trace. I hope you can give me a clue of how to debug it or how the task planning works on `submitToAllMembers`. Thank ya!